# How do you link objects so that they use the same materials?

Tags: materials, objects

I was supposed to link duplicate objects but accidentally used the normal duplicate (shift+D) so changing the materials for all of them manually has become a pain. Does anyone know how to link objects that are already made so they share the same materials without joining the objects into a single one?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Select all your objects, make sure that the last object you select is the one with the material you want to link over to the other ones. Than press Ctrl+L and link Materials[image]

And you're all set.